# Range slider filter in ng-repeat (Angular Ranger)

Tags: angularjs, filter, rangeslider

I'm using `Angular Ranger v~0.1.3` in my project. I want to filter my `ng-repeat` according to the sliding event. I tried some methods but nothing seems to work. I'am providing my code below. I want to filter the `ng-repeat` on price

**html**

```
<angular-ranger min="30000" max="200000" step="1" min-value="value.min" max-value="value.max"></angular-ranger>
<div ng-repeat="data in assets|filter:rangeFilter">
  Property: {{data.name}}
  price: {{data.price}}
</div>
```

**controller**

```
$scope.assets= data.assets;
$scope.value = {
    min: 30000,
    max: 200000
};
```

Comment: Go here for an working answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35080746/filter-ng-repeat-on-range-slider-angular-js

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert in `angular-ranger` library but I took a quick look at the api and it looks like there is no `rangeFilter` filter exposed in it. It only works with `<angular-ranger>` directive and values are directly bound to yours `$scope.value`.

What might be worth trying your is to put `<angular-ranger>` directive inside of `ng-repeat` and putting `min, max` on the `$scope.assets`!

Hope that helps! :)

Comment: okay can you give me an example using range-slider @Novarac23

Comment: @Ranjith what are you exactly trying to achieve ? I need a bit more insight in order to provide the code that works for your actual use case.