# Filter ng-repeat on range slider angular js

Tags: angularjs, filter, rangeslider

i'm using rangle slider on my project. i want to filter the ng-repeat on sliding of range slider. i want to filter the data on the price. my code
html:-

```
<range-slider min="slider.min" max="slider.max" step="slider.step" lower-value="slider.min" upper-value="slider.max"></range-slider>
 <div ng-repeat="data in data|filter:rangeFilter()">
    Property: {{data.name}}
    price: {{data.price}}
 </div>
```

controller:-

```
$scope.data = [{

                 name : hoarding1,
                 price : 50000

                },
                {

                 name : hoarding2,
                 price : 50000

                },
                {

                 name : hoarding3,
                 price : 50000

                }
               ]

$scope.slider = {

    step : 10000,
    min : Math.min.apply(Math,$scope.data.map(function(item){return item.price;})),
    max : Math.max.apply(Math,$scope.data.map(function(item){return item.price;}))

}
$scope.rangeSlider = function (){

 return function( items, rangeInfo ) {
    var filtered = [];
    var min = parseInt(rangeInfo.min);
    var max = parseInt(rangeInfo.max);
    // If time is with the range
    angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
        if( item.price >= min && item.price <= max ) {
            filtered.push(item);
        }
    });
    return filtered;
};
```

this is not worked for me.
Please help me :-(

Comment: Sorry it's not assets it's data that i have provided @Vlad Dekhanov

Comment: Could you share content of your `rangeFilter` object?

Comment: could you please elaborate, you want to filter the object which has only price ? what is rangeFilter

Comment: $scope.rangeSlider = function (){
 
  return function( items, rangeInfo ) {
        var filtered = [];
        var min = parseInt(rangeInfo.min);
        var max = parseInt(rangeInfo.max);
        // If time is with the range
        angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
            if( item.price >= min && item.price <= max ) {
                filtered.push(item);
            }
        });
        return filtered;
    };

Comment: Sorry, but your example doesn't explain what is `rangeFilter`

Comment: i have to show the data blw the range filter according to the price @Vlad Dekhanov

Comment: Perhaps you mixed up your 'rangeFilter' and 'rangeSlider' but even if you would change it to one name you would use wrong.

Comment: rangeFilter means that i want to filter the ng-repeat data items in b/w the range-slider selection according to the price in data set @shushanth p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think u need a custom filter which filters for a particular price and show the particular item which has the filter boundary on the price , please see the below code

**controller :**

```
$scope.rangeInfo = {
    min : Math.min.apply(Math,$scope.data.map(function(item){return item.price;})),
    max : Math.max.apply(Math,$scope.data.map(function(item){return item.price;}))
  }
```

**template**:

```
<div ng-repeat="data in data | priceRange:rangeInfo">
    Property: {{data.name}}
    price: {{data.price}}

 </div>
```

**filter**

you can use forEach array method or filter method of array(ES5)

```
app.filter('priceRange',function(){
  return function(arrayItems,rangeInfo){
     return arrayItems.filter(function(item){
       console.log(item.price);
       return (item.price > rangeInfo.min && item.price < rangeInfo.max);
     }); 
    } 
  });
```

ES2015 (ES6) filter method using arrow functions

```
   app.filter('priceRange',function(){

      return function(arrayItems,rangeInfo){

         return arrayItems.filter((item) => (item.price > rangeInfo.min && item.price < rangeInfo.max));
      }

});
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/JQgcEsW4NIaAwDVAcfy0?p=preview

Comment: @Ranjith , sure ! , no problem . i'm glad it worked for u.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to implement your custom filter you should check info here
https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09

After creation your custom filter you should use it like below:

```
<div ng-repeat="data in data | customFilterName">
```

**Note:** i suggest you to don't use name for each instance of data like `data` also. Perhaps could be better `'item in data'` or smth like that.